# Converting recursive combination-finding algorithm to iterative to avoid GC Overhead Limit Exceeded error

Tags: java, recursion, garbage-collection, iteration, combinations

This algorithm's purpose is to generate a list of sequences of trips.  Each trip has a start point and and end point. The user specifies both of those, and every sequence in the list returned by the algorithm must ultimately begin with a trip that has the specified start point and end with a trip that has the specified end point.

I came up with an algorithm that returns every possible sequence that starts with a trip that has the specified start point (e.g. for start A, possible first trips include AB, AC, AD, etc.). After getting that list of sequences, my plan was to remove every sequence that does not end with a trip that has the specified end (e.g. for end C, sequences with final trips BA, CD, and DB would be removed from the list).

```
public List<ArrayList<Trip>> getTripSequences(List<Trip> tripList, Location start, List<Trip> sequence) {

    List<ArrayList<Trip>> resultList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Trip>>();

    getTripSequences(tripList, start, sequence, resultList);

    return resultList;
}

private void getTripSequences(List<Trip> tripList, Location start, List<Trip> sequence, List<ArrayList<Trip>> resultList) {
    if (tripList.isEmpty())
        return;

    else {
        for (Trip trip : tripList)

            if (trip.getStart().equals(start)) {

                // intermSq - an intermediary sequence
                ArrayList<Trip> intermSq = new ArrayList<Trip>();

                List<Trip> smallerList = new ArrayList<Trip>();

                smallerList.addAll(tripList);

                intermSq.addAll(sequence);

                intermSq.add(trip);

                resultList.add(intermSq);

                smallerList.remove(trip);

                resultList.addAll(getTripSequences(smallerList, trip.getEnd(), intermSq));      
            }   
     }
}
```

The algorithm works properly for small lists of trips. For example, entering the following list of possible trips

```
AB, BA, BC, CA, CB
```

with a specified start point of A would return the following sequences:

```
AB
AB BA
AB BC
AB BC CA
AB BC CB
AB BC CB BA
```

Of course, after this point, I'd have to remove every sequence that doesn't end with the proper end location, but that doesn't seem too difficult.  The problem arises when I attempt to use this with a large list of trips with a larger number of locations than I used in my test (i.e. A B C D).  I get this error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I'm new to the concept of recursion, so I didn't anticipate this problem, but I understand now why it's happening.  I'm trying to decide what I should do instead of this.

- What would an iterative version of this algorithm look like? Would iteration use a sufficiently smaller amount of memory?
- Is it a good idea to just increase the heap size to avoid this error?

I've tried to completely rewrite the algorithm to solve the main problem (i.e. generating sequences with the specified start and end points), but I'm very much stuck.

I'd be grateful for any help!

EDIT
Here are the classes used in the algorithm.

```
public class Location {

    private String continent;
    private String country;

    public Location(){
        super();
    }

    public Location(String continent, String country) {
        super();
        this.continent = continent;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getContinent() {
        return continent;
    }

    public void setContinent(String continent) {
        this.continent = continent;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }   
}

public class Trip {

    private Location start;
    private Location end;

    public Location getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(Location start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public Location getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(Location end) {
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

EDIT
The following generator creates a list that is the size of the one that causes my error.

```
public class Tester {

    public Trip makeTrip(Location start, Location end) {
        Trip trip = new Trip();
        trip.setStart(start);
        trip.setEnd(end);
        return trip;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Tester tester = new Tester();

    ArrayList<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();

    locations.add(new Location("A", "A"));
    locations.add(new Location("B", "B"));
    locations.add(new Location("C", "C"));
    locations.add(new Location("D", "D"));
    locations.add(new Location("E", "E"));
    locations.add(new Location("F", "F"));
    locations.add(new Location("G", "G"));
    locations.add(new Location("H", "H"));
    locations.add(new Location("I", "I"));
    locations.add(new Location("J", "J"));
    locations.add(new Location("K", "K"));
    locations.add(new Location("L", "L"));
    locations.add(new Location("M", "M"));
    locations.add(new Location("N", "N"));
    locations.add(new Location("O", "O"));
    locations.add(new Location("P", "P"));
    locations.add(new Location("Q", "Q"));
    locations.add(new Location("R", "R"));
    locations.add(new Location("S", "S"));
    locations.add(new Location("T", "T"));

    int i = 0;

    Random random = new Random();

    ArrayList<Trip> trips = new ArrayList<Trip>();

    while (i++ < 54) {
        trips.add(tester.makeTrip(locations.get(random.nextInt(20)), locations.get(random.nextInt(20))));
    }

    System.out.println(trips.size());

    for (Trip trip : trips)

    System.out.println(trip.getStart().getCountry() + trip.getEnd().getCountry());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! its possible to you put a little project with the classes used in this algorithm, i can't understand exatly this recursion you are doing, but looks like it need to be rewrited because its not so complex that you need to increase the heap size for it.

Comment: @KennedyOliveira I've added the classes that the algorithm uses.  I agree that it should not require me to increase the heap size.  I've been thinking for a while about how to do this another way, and I haven't made much progress.

Comment: Can you add some input for the test? I mean, some that that leads to OutOfMemory? So i can simulate, profile and check the gaps to help you

Comment: @KennedyOliveira I've added a class to my post that will generate a list the size of the one that leads to the memory error.

Comment: check if i'm correct, i posted the results of the refactored algorithm but i'm not sure if i changed you logic, check the result: http://pastebin.com/fCtTb5kD
If its correct i'll post what i did.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment link, check this one please: http://pastebin.com/ZchNhj2K

Comment: @KennedyOliveira In a single sequence, I'm trying to make the destination of each trip be the origin of the next trip.  For example, a valid sequence could be DC CA AF FO OT.  Each letter combination represents a trip, with 1st letter as the start point and 2nd letter as the end point. An example from your results: `[Trip{start=GG, end=SS}, Trip{start=RR, end=LL}, Trip{start=RR, end=LL}]`  The 1st trip ends with S and the 2nd trip starts with R.  Instead, the 2nd trip should start with S. So this isn't exactly what I'm trying to return. I really appreciate you trying to help me though!

Comment: ahh @rattata, now i understand, so should be something like this http://pastebin.com/9jgyPGB7

Comment: @KennedyOliveira Your output looks correct.  I ran my algorithm with the same arguments (trip starts and ends) and got the same output that you did.

Comment: OK, i did this algorithm using "brute force" testing all combinations, works, don't use much memory, but takes much time, i guess yours too, my doubt is, there is a time restriction? in how long time you need to retrieve the results from this method?

Comment: @KennedyOliveira This function will ultimately be called by a user action on the client side of an application.  So, in the real world, it's best if that kind of function is fast.  But for what I'm doing, as long as it actually works, I'm not really concerned if the function is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the same algorithm using math combination by the lib (Combinatoricslib)

Here is the code, it use alot less memory, but stills takes long because use brute force, trying all possible combination and filtering the ones the match the rules.

You'll need java 8 to compile this, check if suits your needs.

[The Lib](https://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/)

[Algorithm refactored](http://pastebin.com/5uPtB9Qg)

Comment: It works!  I've tested this with a list that has 15 elements.  I've also attempted to test with a list the size of the one that caused my issue, but I ended up stopping it because it had been running for at least 10 minutes. So, I might try to think of a faster method.

In any case, thank you for your help, Kennedy!

Comment: Glad to help! Like i said, this logic use brute force, make all possible combination and then filter this combination, so, if you have to many itens in the list it 'll take sometime, thats why i asked you about the time being a problem or not, its just like your own algorithm but doens't use too much memory.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a classic memory problem.

1. Check your code: You call the `getTripSequences` function recursive in a `for` loop. That is not optimal at all.
2. Increase your memory size to `-Xmx512m` or even `-Xmx1024m`

Comment: I call the function in a for loop because I need this action to be applied to every trip in the list.  How could I change this to make it more optimal?

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit` exceeded is not a "real" out of memory error. This means the GC is trying to run, but it is taking too long to figure out what it can cleanup so it bails. I've run into this issue before in various complicated situations where the GC is having a hard time figuring out what it can free and is a borderline bug. The solution is to use the JVM parameter `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`. You may still get a memory error since you are doing some very expensive operations, but it may find some free space and let you continue.

Also, pull those two variable definitions `intermSq` and `smallerList` out of the middle of the for loop as a minor optimization. You may also want to consider initializing them to the correct size if it potentially big, otherwise you have a lot of memory shuffling.

Comment: Is the overhead limit larger than 2GB?  That's what I changed my heap size to.  I placed -Xmx2g in the run configuration (I'm using Eclipse). It still can't get through the method. This is evidence of how abysmal my algorithm is, I guess.  Thank you for your suggestion, though.

Comment: The overhead limit I'm speaking of is time based.